# XAML Tooltip's StringFormat DateTime does not append a string

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I have triggers where tooltip flips date formating. Both triggers work. However, when I apply the string formatting to the first one and add/append to DateTime value a string "UTC", the date shows up correctly with correct datetime formatting, but the "UTC" part doesn't append:

```
....
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowUTC}" Value="True">           
      <Setter TargetName="brd" Property="Border.ToolTip" 
              Value="{Binding Path=SomeDate, 
               <!--Problem on the line below - the 'UTC' part isn't being added -->
               StringFormat={}{0:ddd MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss} UTC}" />
   </DataTrigger>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowUTC}" Value="False">
       <Setter TargetName="brd" Property="Border.ToolTip" 
               Value="{Binding SomeDate, 
               Converter={StaticResource ToLocalTime}}"/>
   </DataTrigger>
 .....
```

this should work per MSDN: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx
I also tried it with other types and had it work, is there something with DateTime?

UPDATE:

What's interesting is that using the same code works on the TextBlock:

```
Text="{Binding Path=EndInterval, StringFormat={}{0:ddd MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss} UTC}"
```

but not on the tooltip:

```
<Border Tooltip="{Binding Path=EndInterval, StringFormat={}{0:ddd MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss} UTC}"
```

Comment: Found good working solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509627/wpf-tooltip-binding-with-stringformat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for anyone who hits the same issue, I'll post what I ended up doing.

Since I couldn't get the StringFormat work directly on the ToolTip. 
I ended up styling it and applying the StringFormat to the `TextBlock` inside the ToolTip directly:

```
<Border ..>
  <Border.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip>
       <TextBlock>
          <TextBlock.Style>
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Text" 
                        Value="{Binding Path=SomeDate, 
                                        Converter={StaticResource ToLocalTime}}"/>
                   <Style.Triggers>
                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowUtc}" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=SomeDate, 
                                   StringFormat={}{0:ddd MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss} UTC}"/>
                       </DataTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
           </TextBlock.Style>
       </TextBlock>
     </ToolTip>
  </Border.ToolTip>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since binding is to ToolTip, it is implicitly setting the Content property. ToolTips have a ContentFormatString property that you use when you want to format. I haven't tested it but I think the below will work.

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowUTC}" Value="True">           
    <Setter TargetName="brd" Property="Border.ToolTip" 
            Value="{Binding Path=SomeDate}" />
    <Setter TargetName="brd" Property="Border.ToolTip.ContentFormatString" 
            Value="{}{0:ddd MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss} UTC" />
  </DataTrigger>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowUTC}" Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="brd" Property="Border.ToolTip" 
            Value="{Binding SomeDate, 
            Converter={StaticResource ToLocalTime}}"/>
  </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know that +1! I'll check it out. My only reservation is on `Border.ToolTip.ContentFormatString` - I have had mixed results with nesting more than 2 level deep.

Comment: yeah.. triple nesting didn't compile, but would've been cool.

Comment: To add to @denismorozov comment, the above solution neither compiles nor works.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to resort to a converter because nothing I found on SO worked.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Converters
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(string))]
    public class DateTimeStringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is DateTime && parameter != null)
                return ((DateTime)value).ToString(parameter.ToString());
            return value;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Border ToolTip="{Binding DateTime, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeStringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter=yyyy}"/>
```

Simple, yet effective.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with that `StringFormat`. I can see the `UTC` when using this simple code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat={}{0:ddd MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss} UTC}" />
```

Therefore, I suggest to you that perhaps the end of the text is getting cut off, either by an overlaying control, or by the control displaying the text not being wide enough.  Either way, if you try this simplified code, you'll see that it works and therefore that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: oh, I didn't think of the text possibly getting cut off! That's a possibility, I'll check that out, Thank you! +1! Now that I think about more, the Width gets set by the first triggered text, which is shorter, and doesn't get resized for the second for some reason.

Comment: After some testing, I see that it does work on the textblock, but not on the tooltip, weird.. I guess I will have to create a Template for the tooltip and stuff a textblock in there

Comment: thanks for your post again, your sample with the `TextBlock` instead of a `ToolTip` pointed me into solution area.