# WPF - ToolTip Binding with stringformat

Tags: wpf, binding, tooltip, string-formatting

I want to make a tool tip using binding and string format, he is what I've tried:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat='The name is: {0}{}'}"/>
```

The value of Name is :

> Golan

What I expected to see is:

> The name is: Golan

But all is see is:

> Golan

Comment: You have to surround your tooltip with `"` and close the last `}` of the binding.

Comment: I copied that from my work computer, forgot to do that, edited my question, here is the real code

Comment: Delete the `'` chars

Comment: this question has a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25055900/692829

Answer (score 11):

I think you can use this code

```
<TextBlock Width="100" x:Name="tt" Text="{Binding Name}">
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip  Width="100"
            Content="{Binding Name}"
            ContentStringFormat="The Name is: {0}"
        />
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```